# Trouble getting SSL to work with django + nginx + wsgi

Tags: ssl, nginx, mod-wsgi

I've followed a couple of examples for Django + nginx + wsgi + ssl, but I can't get them to work.  I simply get an error in my browser than I can't connect.

I'm running two websites off the host.  The config files are identical except for the ip addresses, server names, and directories.

When neither use SSL, they work fine.  When I try to listen on 443 with one of them, I can't connect to either.

My config files are below, and any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
server{
listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
server_name sub.domain.com;

access_log /home/django/logs/nginx_customerdb_http_access.log;
error_log /home/django/logs/nginx_customerdb_http_error.log;

location / { 
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080; 
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90; 
    proxy_send_timeout      90; 
    proxy_read_timeout      90; 
    proxy_buffers           32 4k; 
}   

location /site_media/ {
    alias /home/django/customerdb_site_media/;
}   

location /admin-media/ {
    alias /home/django/django_admin_media/;
}   
}

server{
listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443;
server_name sub.domain.com;

access_log /home/django/logs/nginx_customerdb_http_access.log;
error_log /home/django/logs/nginx_customerdb_http_error.log;

ssl on; 
ssl_certificate sub.domain.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key sub.domain.com.key;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on; 


location / { 
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080; 
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol    https;
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_buffers           32 4k;
}

location /site_media/ {
    alias /home/django/customerdb_site_media/;
}

location /admin-media/ {
    alias /home/django/django_admin_media/;
}
}


<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ServerAlias xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /home/django/logs/apache_customerdb_error.log
CustomLog /home/django/logs/apache_customerdb_access.log combined

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/customerdb/apache/django.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess customerdb_wsgi processes=4 threads=5
WSGIProcessGroup customerdb_wsgi

SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Protocol "^https$" HTTPS=on

</VirtualHost>
```

UDPATE: the existence of two sites (on separate IPs) on the host is the issue.  if i delete the other site, the setting above mostly work.  doing so also brings up another issue: chrome doesn't accept the site as secure saying that some content is not encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the server that listens on 80 to rewrite to https removed all the other directives.

Answer (score 2):

[This should actually be a comment ...]

You should also set

`proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol  $scheme`

To indicate to Django when connections are secure, otherwise your https links will get redirected to http, which is bad.

This will set `http` when it actually is `http`, and `https` when it's `https`.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header for the matching setting on Django 1.4+.